# Generating a JSON file from Excel to be read it in Python

Tags: python, json, excel, vba, utf-8

I have a quite big Excel file containing several tables.
I was able to serialize them into JSONs using an ADODB.Stream in VBA code:

This is VBA code:

```vb
Dim st As ADODB.Stream
  ' create a stream object
Set st = New ADODB.Stream
' set properties
st.Charset = "utf-8"
st.Type = adTypeText
' open the stream object and write some text
st.Open
st.WriteText myString
st.SaveToFile filepath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
st.Close
```

Now I want to read it in Python to pass it to a data frame with:

This is Python code:

```
import JSON
with open(myfilecomplete) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 407330: character maps to

The file is quite big (1MB of text). I dont even know how to find character 407330.

Besides I am supposed to be writting in disc in uft-8 the most common encoding form. Right?

Why is JSON not able to undecode utf-8?

EDIT AFTER ANSWER / WARNING: Don't try to serialise a JSON file from Excel manually. this will end up giving errors almost always. Use a proper library for doing that like in [here](http://excelerator.solutions/2017/08/24/convert-excel-to-json-using-vba/):

Comment: very good point, but now I get: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Actually reading in the error message I can see in the traceback: if s.startswith('\ufeff'): raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)"  So the problem is that \ufeff character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it :

```py
with open(myfilecomplete, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

[Here some documentation](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2019/04/python-fixing-unexpected-utf-8-bom-error-when-loading-json-data/)

Comment: In any case serializing to JSON from excel is a nightmare, all the puntuation including in the cells makes the resulting JSON broken. I am just realizing. I thought passing all those tables to JSON would let me wrok straight away in python,... nopp

Comment: perhaps trying it directly from python with a convinient lybrary like xlwings

Comment: @Berlines, could you use pandas to parse your excel file ?

Comment: The problem is that I VBA-manually generated the JSON files. Those are broken because my texts include punctuation. It wont fly. I will try with xlwings. I will report here if it works but it will take a while.

Comment: To be more precise, the UFT-8 problem is solve, but the JSONs are broken.

Comment: follow also this other question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363939/open-and-fetch-data-from-a-listobject-of-an-excel-sheet-with-python

Comment: I will try with pandas anyway, because you serialize you excel file with VBA, but I don't know why you can simply do pd.read_excel("big_excel.xlsx") and then clean each tables and finaly merge them.

Comment: Ok I see now, I will check it

Comment: because I have tables in the sheets and I dont know how to access the tables (Listobjects)

Comment: I just tried: nameExcel='EPO2019-10wk42.xlsm'
myfilecomplete=os.path.join(mypath,nameExcel)
df = pd.read_excel(myfilecomplete, sheet_name='SC') It works, but in sheet "SC" I have a ListObject. In this way of doing gets the WHOLE sheet.